# ffmpeg encoding options to maximise Windows 7 compatibility?

Tags: windows-7, video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.264

I'd like to encode a few short (e.g. 30 seconds-ish) video clips with a goal of maximising their out-of-the-box compatibility with Windows 7.

Specifically, what ffmpeg encoding parameters should I use to make the output video work with a *completely plain/vanilla* installation of Windows 7 SP1? (**without installing anything else, no codec packs, no VLC, etc.**)

My guess is that H.264 (or MPEG-4?) would work, but even so what other encoding paramaters should I use to maximise the chances of the videos playing without a hitch? What about audio? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic command below will get you a vanilla MP4

```
ffmpeg -i in -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

I would have omitted the profile and the forced stereo channel count (`-ac 2`) normally, but for pre-emptive compatibility, they are safer to have.

Comment: Thank you @Mulvya! So H.264 is indeed supported... I guess I wouldn't need to consider MPEG-4, then?

Comment: @hpy If Mulvya's command works then there is no need to output MPEG-4 Part 2 video (which is what you get if using `-c:v mpeg4`).

Comment: All codecs and containers listed with Windows Vista or higher should be good: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard and @Mulvya! Understood. That said, out of curiosity, how do I get ffmpeg to encode MPEG-4 v1/v2/v3?

Comment: `MPEG-4 v1/v2/v3` looks to be idiosyncratic terminology used by Microsoft. AFAICT, they are MS implementations of MPEG-4 Part 2 codec, so `-c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 5` in place of `-c:v libx264 -profile:v main`

Comment: Got it, thanks @Mulvya! I wish there's a table or something that clears this up all this terminology... Oh, and does `qscale:v` affect compatibility??

Comment: No, it affects quality and thus size.

Comment: @hpy You can encode the Microsoft MPEG-4 Part 2 variants "MPEG v2/v3" with `-c:v msmpeg4v2` & `-c:v msmpeg4v3`. I've never tried them.

Comment: Thank you @LordNeckbeard!! That's great to know. I just tried it but for some reason my virtual vanilla Windows installation claims it doesn't recognise that format...